# How do I get spring security to work with embedded jetty?

Tags: java, spring

I have been trying to get spring security to work with an embedded jetty server.  I followed the example here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-reactive-spring-web

I getting the following error.

```
12:57:48.712 [qtp778330045-22] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request (org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper and org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.JettyHttpHandlerAdapter$JettyServerHttpRequest.createHeaders(JettyHttpHandlerAdapter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.JettyHttpHandlerAdapter$JettyServerHttpRequest.<init>(JettyHttpHandlerAdapter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.JettyHttpHandlerAdapter.createRequest(JettyHttpHandlerAdapter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter.service(ServletHttpHandlerAdapter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:743)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The problem is that the SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter is modifying the request, so that when the JettyHttpHandlerAdapter tries to cast it back to a Request object a ClassCastException is thrown.  I am not sure how the spring security chain and the JettyHttpHandlerAdapter.

```java
package com.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.test;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.HttpHandler;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.JettyHttpHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;
import org.springframework.web.server.adapter.WebHttpHandlerBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
@ComponentScan("com.test")
@Import(ApplicationSecurity.class)
public class JettyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public Server jettyServer(ApplicationContext context, Filter springSecurityFilterChain) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();

        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "");

        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setHost("localhost");
        connector.setPort(8080);

        HttpHandler httpHandler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(context).build();

        HttpServlet servlet = new ServletHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);

        JettyHttpHandlerAdapter servlet = new JettyHttpHandlerAdapter(WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(context).build());
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), "/");
        servletContextHandler.addFilter(new FilterHolder(new DelegatingFilterProxy(springSecurityFilterChain)), "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

        server.addConnector(connector);
        server.start();
        return server;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't simply use spring-boot ? It already configure what you are trying to do out of the box....